# How do I hide the panel on my button click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I'm working on the main menu for the game, where I have options to join or create a room. Under the *Create* button, I made an *Advanced* button which will open the advanced panel, giving the user more options, such as room size. I made the correct `onclick()` event which uses `SetActive` property of both the main menu panel and the advanced panel.

> [image: screenshot]

The problem is, that when I click the button, the advanced menu appears but the main menu doesn't hide. I've looked at different tutorials, but they all say to do exactly what I've done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually use these build in methods. The best way is to create your own implementation like so:

```
public GameObject panel; // drop the panel in the editor

public void onAdvancedClicked()
{
   panel.SetActive(!panel.activeSelf); // make it active/inactive with one click
}
```

The other way to initialize your `panel` in the script is by adding tag to it and getting it by tag like so in your start method:

```
panel = GameObject.FindWithTag("panelTag");
```

Comment: And I almost never use the Inspector UI for this (as I frequently want to pass values to my functions!) and end up doing everything through code using `GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { ... })`